# Где хранятся истории запросов к бд на сервере?

Tags: mysql, centos

Скажите, пож-ста, где хранятся истории запросов на сервере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для включения лога:

```
SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

Для просмотра:

```
SELECT * FROM `general_log`
```